# How to find the general form (Ax-By-C = 0) of a line with an undefined slope

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is how the question reads:
"The equation of the line that goes through the points (3, -6) and (3, 10) can be written in general form Ax + By + C = 0 where A = **_ B = _** and C = ____" I know the answer for B is 0 but am unable to find the solutions for A and B. Please help!

Comment: I meant A and C. I know the answer to B, not A or C.

Comment: So you are submitting $A=1$, $B=0$, and $C=3$?

Comment: It id still unclear to me if you are submitting $C=3$ or $C=-3$.  Which one is the WebWork telling you is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a vertical line since it passes through two points with the same horizontal coordinate ($3$). Vertical lines always have an equation of the form $x=k$. In this case, $k=3$ by inspection. In your general form this is

$$1x-0y-3=0,$$

right?

**Addendum:** It would be very much worth your time to memorize the fact that vertical (horizontal, resp.) lines have equations of the form $x=k$ ($y=k$, resp.), and that they are characterized by the fact that all points on them have the same horizontal (vertical, resp.) coordinate.

Comment: Thats what I've been plugging into the WebWorks system and it has been saying that that solution is incorrect. Very confused because that's the only answer I can come to as well.

Comment: I've always seen general form written as $Ax +By +C=0$. Note the sign differences. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: If that is the problem then it sounds horribly formatted.

Comment: That is how it is formatted. But the coefficients for A and C are still incorrect.

Comment: Of course, without any sort of normalization, general form is not unique. @oliveeuler: I'm not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a vertical line. The x-coordinate is always equal to $3$, so we can write $x=3$. This is in fact the equation of the line. Let's put it into general form.

$$
\begin{align}
&x=3 \\
&x-3=0 \\
&1x-0y-3=0 \\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $A=1$, $B=0$ and $C=-3$.

Comment: Except that there is already an extra minus sign attached to $B$ and $C$ in the general form the OP uses, so here you should have $C=+3$, not $-3$, right?

Comment: @MPW Title says general form is $ax-by-c=0$, but in the actual question, op says $ax+by+c=0$ is the general form (which I am used to)

Comment: Yep, you're right, didn't notice that. I thought the minus signs were peculiar, never have seen that. Guess they don't belong there after all, and I see why OP's answer was rejected. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is another example of procedures getting in the way of common sense.

Plot the points $(3, -6)$ and $(3, 10)$ on a Cartesian plane. Did you notice that a line through these points is just a vertical line where $x=3$? Rearranging into the form of $Ax+By+C=0$, we have $1x+0y+(-3)=0$.

Comment: Isn't this what **all** of the other answers are pointing out?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I believe though that the problem is 2 fold. First, its an algebra problem. Secondly (and what I really wanted to point out), I believe that Quinn is trying to apply a procedure blindly, and inappropriately, where common sense should prevail. I think that perhaps he is trying to solve a system of equations in 2 variables,but because $B=0$, the system is linearly dependent.